# Ajax not working in a jQuery Mobile popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, popup

I am using a jQuery mobile popup as an editing form. When the user clicks a submit button, it should take the info on the form and do an SQL query to update the database. For some reason as soon as it gets to the ajax call, it breaks. I have tried using a normal submit button and also just a normal button that's binded to a jQuery function and both do the same thing.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("checkpoint 1");
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: process_edit.php,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            //do something
        }
    } );
    alert("checkpoint 2");
});
```

I get the "checkpoint 1" alert box to show up, but then the jQuery mobile popup closes and "checkpoint 2" never shows up.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: @MikeBrant Nope, no errors.

Comment: try adding `.fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)` and/or `.error(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)` and see if there are any errors thrown there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo error you missed the single quotes `'` around the `url` part

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("checkpoint 1");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process_edit.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            //do something
        }
    });
    alert("checkpoint 2");
});
```